# Props values in react router render method are not updated with Firebase firestore onsnapshot realtime update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

```
const [documents, setDocuments] = useState()

useEffect(()=>{     
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('Documents')
      .onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
        const myDocuments = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id : doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }))
        setDocuments(myDocuments)
      })

      return () =>unsubscribe()
  },[])

if(documents)
  return (
    <div >
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} documents={documents} />}  />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  )
  else return <Spinner/>
```

When there are changes in the collection 'Documents' (for example, a new document is added or a field of an exisiting document is updated), "documents" will be updated with new state. But in Dashboard, the documents passed into the props are still the previous documents value with no new changes. I thought 'Dashboard' will automatically receive updated props values of documents but it didn't.

```
 <Route exact path="/"component={()=><ViewDocumentTable documents={documents} />} />
```

If I write the code this way, it will always receive the latest updated props values. But, I am aware that this is not a good solution because this causes the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component. The performance will be greatly affected.

Can someone tell me how to always get the updated values through the props in React Router ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<Route exact path="/" component = {() => <Dashboard documents={documents}} />
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it still does not work. The documents in useEffect are always updated even if there is no 'documents' as the second parameter. The problem is the props in the Route only stores the previous old values of documents.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out myself. Actually it is working. It didn't work in my case because of my own silly mistakes. Thanks everyone who helped here.